# How to use redis pipeline to get all updates to db at once?

Tags: c++, redis

I use [redis++](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) library and have a redis db which contains keys with ttl set. I want to be informed for all updates to my db. I set `__keyevent@0__:set` and a subscriber callback like this

```
subscriber.on_message([&keys = updated_redis_keys](std::string, std::string key) {
  keys.push_back(std::move(key));
});
```

and use a while loop to consume events:

```
while (true)
{
  try
  {
    subscriber.consume();

    for (const auto &key : keys)
      pipeline.get(key).ttl(key);

    auto replies = pipeline.exec();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < keys.size(); ++i)
    {
      static constexpr std::size_t ValueIndex = 0;
      static constexpr std::size_t TtlIndex = 1;

      const auto value = replies.get<std::optional<std::string>>(i * 2 + ValueIndex);
      const auto ttl = replies.get<long long>(i * 2 + TtlIndex);
      const auto entry = Entry(std::move(updated_redis_keys[i]), *value, static_cast<std::size_t>(ttl));

      do_something_with(entry);
    }

    keys.clear();
  }
  catch (const sw::redis::Error &err)
  {
  }
    
}
```

I tried to accumulate keys in `keys` vector and use `pipeline.exec()` to get values and ttl of all updated keys at once. But i think `subscriber.consume();` just consumes a single event each time so `keys.size()` always equals to 1.

How can i get better performance by stacking more keys before running exec()?

Answer (score 1):

You can collect a batch of keys by running multiple `consume()`s before running the pipeline. Even better, you can have a time window threshold, and run the pipeline when reaching the threshold (even if we have not collected enough keys).

```
const int batch_size = 10;
const std::chrono::seconds time_threshold(30);

while (true) {
    auto cnt = 0;
    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<std::string> keys;
    while (cnt < batch_size && std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - begin < time_threshold) {
        // Not get enough keys, and we still have time, do consume.
        try {
            subscriber.consume();
        } catch (const Error &e) {
            // handle errors.
        }
        ++cnt;
    }
    // now we've gotten a batch of keys or reached the time threshold. do the pipeline job.
    // your original code here.
}
```